# How can I determine the length of time an item is trending on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

Basically I am watching the worldwide trending list and I would like to know how can I figure out the length of time [Inception](http://twitter.com/search?q=Inception) has been trending ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TweetStats](http://tweetstats.com/) has a page with [Trend Stats](http://tweetstats.com/trends).  If you hover over a bar in the bar graph it shows you the duration.
[image: Trends screengrab]

Comment: sweet ! 93.30 hours / 24 that puts it at approx 4 days of continuous trending ?